# Can the problem of serialization gadgets arise in static serializers?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

Jackson serializer seems to have a potential gadget exploitation problem in certain conditions as explained in this [blog](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/on-jackson-cves-dont-panic-here-is-what-you-need-to-know-54cd0d6e8062). One way to understand this problem is, since Jackson is a runtime serializer, it is having loose ends that can be exploited while deserializing data to java.lang.Object, java.io.Serializable, java.util.Comparable, etc.

So, can we say that static serializers like [Borer](https://github.com/sirthias/borer) will not have such loose ends since you need `decoders` of the models at compile time ?